# Reading from Excel table gives wrong value

Tags: excel, vb.net

I want to read from a TimeTable. Unfortunately that doesn't work. Instead of `"3:53"` at B1, the program reads and shows `0.16`. How can I improve this?
I am using `Microsoft.Office.Interop`.
I have already tried to change the formatting in the table - to no avail.

```
Private xlApp As Excel.Application = New Excel.Application
Private xlWorkBook As Excel.Workbook
'in a Sub:
xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(filepath)
 Dim xlWorkSheet As Excel.Worksheet = CType(xlWorkBook.Worksheets("L7"), Excel.Worksheet)
        Dim xlRange As Excel.Range = xlWorkSheet.UsedRange
        Dim ER As Excel.Range
        Dim ER2 As Excel.Range
        Dim Index As Integer = 0
        For Zeile As Integer = 1 To xlRange.Rows.Count
            ER = CType(xlRange.Cells(Zeile, 1), Excel.Range)
            ER2 = CType(xlRange.Cells(Zeile, 2), Excel.Range)
            If CStr(ER2.Value) = "..." Then
                Continue For
            End If
        Dim gesplittet As String() = CStr(ER2.Value).Split(":"c)
'...
```

`ER.Value` becomes 0.16 instead of "3:53". I want to have a String.

[image: TimeTable]

Comment: Just format it as time.  `0.161805555555556` is how `3:53` is stored by Excel

Comment: The last line of code posted implies that you are extracting the hours/minutes information from the time value.  Excel cells formatted as Time are retrieved as a Double data type as you have found.  You can use the [DateTime.FromOADate(Double) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.fromoadate?view=net-5.0) to convert this value to a DateTime structure (only accurate in the Workbook is not set to use the 1904 date system).  Then you can access the Hour/Minute properties from the DateTime structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Time and date values are usually stored internally totally different in spread sheet and database programs. Therefore you will never get directly the values you see as you get the raw values. In your case it seems like you are getting a time/date value: the date is the value before the dot and the fractional digits are the fraction of the 24 hour day.

```
0.16 * 24 = 3.84 hours
```

Which means 3 hours and 0.84 of one hour:

```
0.84 * 60 = 50.4 minutes
```

I assume the small difference to your expected value is because the value 0.16 was a rounded value. Using the exact value and performing the calculations should get you the expected result.

Comment: Many Thanks. I just sent the question when it occurred to me,too 